# Does anyone know how to do convex optimization in Python with CVXOPT module?

Tags: python, cvxopt

I want to maximize `Ax = b` where `A` is an `m`-by-`n` matrix and `x` is an `n`-vector. The constraints on `x` are that its entries sum to `1` and that `A x >= 0`.

Comment: Rodrigo de Azevedo No in fact I want to maximize the summation of this vector elements. Max( sigma (bi))

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo No in fact I want to maximize the summation of this vector elements. Max( sigma (bi)) –

Comment: No, sorry the editor has changed my notations. The summation on the x vector is 1. summation(xi) = 1.

Comment: No I dont want to maximize x, I want to maximize Ax.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you want to maximize. Maximizing ```Ax``` is ambiguous.

Comment: No Maximization on the summation of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org) instead:

```
from cvxpy import *
import numpy as np

m = 30
n = 10

# generate random data
np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.randn(m,n)
b = np.random.randn(m)

# optimization variable
x = Variable(n)

# build optimization problem
prob = Problem( Maximize(sum(A*x)), [ sum(x) == 1, A*x >= 0 ])

# solve optimization problem and prints results
result = prob.solve()
print x.value
```

This optimization problem is **unbounded** and, thus, there is no optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had problem in installing cvxpy in python in my operating system. That was why I was using cvxopt. I think I need to solve the issue with installation first and then try this piece of code.

Comment: b is just the multiplication result of the matrix and vector.

Comment: Ok, I ran your script but in the line x = Variable(n) it gives me error. AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_root'.

Comment: What is the value of `n`?

Comment: I still do not understand what you're trying to compute.